# Предлагаю метку "частица-не" переименовать в "отрицание-не"

Tags: предложение, статус-так-задумано

Предлагаю метку "частица-не" переименовать в "отрицание-не"
Метка предназначена для вопросов, связанных со слитным или раздельным написанием *не*. Нынешняя формулировка: "Для вопросов, связанных со слитным-раздельным написанием **частицы** «не»", — неверна.

Из Лопатина:

Написания с отрицанием не
Вводные замечания. Написание отрицания не зависит от того, является ли не частью слова (**приставкой**) или отдельным словом — отрицательной **частицей**. **Приставка** не- пишется слитно со следующей за ней частью слова, **частица** не пишется раздельно со следующим за ней словом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, текущая формулировка действительно может порождать некоторую терминологическую путаницу, но хочу заметить, что она вполне корректна. Частица не обязательно морфологический термин, она может иметь значение "часть чего-л." (в данном случае — речи), вспомните, как постфикс -ся раньше также называли частицей.